# How can I bake a rigid body simulation in 2.8?

Tags: physics, baking

I' am completely new to blender. I've read the manual, but it only explains what baking is, but it's not clear how to do the baking itself.
In Cinema 4d it's as simple as going the the cache tab in the physics tag, and pressing bake. So either I' am completely blind or i don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rigid Body Cache]
It's in the *Properties Panel* > *Scene* > *Rigid Body World* > *Cache*